# how to set shipping cost per product

Tags: magento

in magento configuration i have set shipping to be £5. Is there a way to set the shipping price on product level. Obviously there is i just can't find where.

Comment: We really need that Magento Stack Exchange site to ask these things, because this is not really a programming question.

Comment: There is a webapps.stackexchange.com though, which is made for these questions.

Comment: now extension is available please check [Flat Rate Shipping Per Product](http://magematrix.com/flat-rate-shipping-per-product.html) and [Multiple Flat Rate Shipping Per Product](http://magematrix.com/multiple-flat-rate-shipping-per-product.html)

Comment: There is a free extension that does this - Product Rate, allows price per product. http://webshopapps.com/us/free/product-flat-rate-shipping-extension.html

Comment: You can configure shipping rates per product per country using our [Magento Product Shipping Rates per Country](https://plugin.company/magento-extensions/shipping-rates-per-product-per-country.html) extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you always use the same shipping price for a given product regardless destination and date you can use the "weight" attribute as the actual
shipping price with table rates.

- Create a new attribute to display the actual weight of the item on the website
- Change the "weight" attribute setting not to display it on the frontend.
- Re-import product details with the new weight attribute and the magento "weight" attribute with the shipping price in it.
- Create a table for table rates and simply put values in the "Weight (and above)" and "Shipping Price" columns as 0,0; 1,1; 2,2 so on.
- Import the CSV file with the shipping rates

Please note this will add up shipping prices:
for example if you order two product and the shipping price is 4 for product A and it is 5 for product B
the final shiping will be 9.

Answer (score 1):

Magento don’t let you set shipping cost in product level. You can do it by flatrate shipping method
Create a attribute shipping_world and add to your default attribute set.
overwrite/extend the flatrate carrier model of magento.
The value given in shipping_world attribute of product will be the flat shipping rate of that product.

[Check this](http://blog.aajit.com/product-level-shipping-in-magento/)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way with plain Magento. You need some sort of [shipping matrix extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1357/webshopapps-product-matrix-shipping). Be sure to browse through [Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/filter/all/shipping) for other options.