# How to assign different shipping rate to different product in the same cart

Tags: php, magento

I am using the `magento store` and I want to assign different shipping rate for the products in same cart. But not getting how to. 
Means if i am having the products A,B,C in my cart then for the product A it will have shipping rate 5.50 and for each next product B and C it would be 1.50.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's Possible. Your Answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/8048694/1557322

Comment: I didn't get the answer there. any other solution?